# Knockout.js after selecting an option generate another select with same options except the one selected

Tags: knockout.js

I'm a Knockout.js newbie and I'm trying to create a "simple" form.

I'm loading an html view with ajax and I'm applying the binds.

The user can select some addons from a select (which is thrown in the DOM from the server, it is not loaded as JSON), and after selecting a valid one it should create another select with the same options except the one selected previously etc for how many addons there are in the select.

What I have so far

```
<table class="new_account new_account_details">
    <tr data-bind="foreach: new Array(plan_addons_num())">
        <td>
            <select class="plans_plan_addon">
                <option value="">Select</option>
                <option value="1">Addon1</option>
                <option value="2">Addon2</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

var viewModels = {
    planPlans: function () {
        this.plan_addons_num = ko.observable(1);
        this.plan_addon = ko.observable();
        this.plan_addons = ko.observableArray();

//        ko.computed(function () {
//            if (Number(this.plan_addon()) > 0) {
//                this.plan_addons_num(this.plan_addons_num() + 1);
//            }
//        }, this);
    }
};
```

plan_addon I wanted it to be the currently selected addon, but it does not work, if I bind it in the foreach as a value.

I could set the available addons as JSON code somewhere in the HTML for the viewmodel to take it with jquery if it helps.
How could I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When working with knockout I feel it helps to think about things model-first. Plan everything out in the model, and worry about the markup later as the markup should merely be a reflection of the state of the model.

I'm not really sure what you were going for with your existing bindings, but here is how I would go about creating your select controls. Create a foreach binding over an array of the previously selected options, and then add one additional select that contains the remaining options.

```
<table class="new_account new_account_details">
  <tr>
    <!--ko foreach: plan_selectedAddons-->
    <td>
      <select class="plans_plan_addon" data-bind="options: $parent.plan_addons, value: $data" disabled></select>
    </td>
    <!--/ko-->
    <td>
      <select class="plans_plan_addon" data-bind="options: plan_remainingOptions, optionsCaption: 'Select', event: { change: selectAddon }"></select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Here's a full fiddle to demonstrate the javascript:
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4yth34Lp/)

As for populating the options array initially yes I would include that in the JSON instead of trying to scrape it from an existing select on the DOM, but you could always do that with jQuery and then hide the original select.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, knockout is awesome!